# moment.js time not in UTC

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have tried moment.utc() and moment.format('YYYY-MM-DD') in order to try and get the current year, date, and time with hours at midnight.  The problem I am having is that I am getting the year, month, and day correctly but +4 hours for the hours.

```
    function initalize_daterange() {

    console.log("It has been loaded!");

    if( typeof ($.fn.daterangepicker) === 'undefined'){ return; }

    var cb = function(start, end, label) {
    console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
    $('#questionsrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    minimum = Date.parse(start.toISOString()).getTime();
    maximum = Date.parse(end.toISOString()).getTime();
    $(document).trigger("load_chart");
  };

  var optionSet1 = {
    startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
    endDate: moment(),
    minDate: '06/10/2017',
    maxDate: moment(),
    dateLimit: {
    days: 60
    },
    showDropdowns: true,
    showWeekNumbers: true,
    timePicker: false,
    timePickerIncrement: 1,
    timePicker12Hour: true,
    ranges: {
    'Today': [moment(), moment()],
    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
    opens: 'left',
    buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
    applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
    cancelClass: 'btn-small',
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    separator: ' to ',
    locale: {
    applyLabel: 'Submit',
    cancelLabel: 'Clear',
    fromLabel: 'From',
    toLabel: 'To',
    customRangeLabel: 'Custom',
    daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    firstDay: 1
    }
  };

  $('#questionsrange span').html(moment().subtract(29, 'days').format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + moment().format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
  $('#questionsrange').daterangepicker(optionSet1, cb);
  $('#questionsrange').on('show.daterangepicker', function() {
    console.log("show event fired");
  });
  $('#questionsrange').on('hide.daterangepicker', function() {
    console.log("hide event fired");
  });
  $('#questionsrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("apply event fired, start/end dates are " + picker.startDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + " to " + picker.endDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
  });
  $('#questionsrange').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    console.log("cancel event fired");
  });
  $('#options1').click(function() {
    $('#questionsrange').data('daterangepicker').setOptions(optionSet1, cb);
  });
  $('#options2').click(function() {
    $('#questionsrange').data('daterangepicker').setOptions(optionSet2, cb);
  });
  $('#destroy').click(function() {
    $('#questionsrange').data('daterangepicker').remove();
  });

}
```

The code snippet below is giving me the start date and end date but plus 4 hours

```
minimum = Date.parse(start.toISOString()).getTime();
maximum = Date.parse(end.toISOString()).getTime();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Date.parse` instead of using moment? Also, most of the references to moment in your code are `moment()` rather than `moment.utc()`, so that's why it's not in UTC.

Comment: I tried start.format('x') to get unix time in milliseconds but unfortunatly it is still 4 hours off from what I expect, even when using moment.utc()

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. We are not an API tutorial service.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to replace all moment() calls with moment().utc() it would work as expected. See this [fiddle for more info](https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/4/)

```
UTC<br/>
<div id="divUTC"></div><br/>
Your Local Time with respect to above UTC time<br/>
<div id="divLocal">
</div>    

$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        var divUtc = $('#divUTC');
        var divLocal = $('#divLocal');  
        //put UTC time into divUTC  
        divUtc.text(moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));      

        //get text from divUTC and conver to local timezone  
        var localTime  = moment.utc(divUtc.text()).toDate();
        localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        divLocal.text(localTime);        
      },1000);
    });
```